# Неправильно идет добавление в бинарное дерево

Tags: c#, дерево

Пытаюсь реализовать красно-черное дерево на C#. Для начала пытаюсь создать обычное бинарное дерево. Проблема с неправильным добавлением элемента в дерево. Отладочная запись показывает, что все время идет добавление в правое поддерево
Вот класс дерева:

```
class MyTree
{
    public int number;       
    public MyTree left;
    public MyTree right;
}
```

Вот класс, в котором реализовано добавление:

```
    class TreeDictionary
{
    public void Insert(int key, MyTree tree)
    {          
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new MyTree();
            tree.number = key;
            tree.left = null;
            tree.right = null;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", key, tree.number);
            if (key <= tree.number)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Left");
                Insert(key, tree.left);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Right");
                Insert(key, tree.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (tree == null)
{
    tree.number = key;
    ...
```

*Просто "проговорю вслух", что вы пытаетесь сделать:*

Если переданная ссылка на объект `MyTree` на самом деле не ссылается ни на какой объект, то **попробовать перейти по этой нулевой ссылке** (и что-либо изменить в этом самом объекте, в вашем случае поле `number`).

*Как это исправить в контексте задачи, я думаю, вы сообразите.*

---

#### Update на основании комментариев

---

Наиболее простой и удобный способ написать код такого типа - **условиться** (т.е организовать некоторый `Code Contract`), что ссылка на объект `MyTree`, передаваемый методу `Insert` - никогда не является `null`.

*С учетом этого контракта код становится достаточно простым:*

```
public static void Insert(int key, MyTree node)
{
    if (key <= node.key)
    {
        if (node.left == null)
        {
            // Можно оформить как конструктор 'MyTree(int key)'.
            node.left = new MyTree();
            node.left.key = key;
            // Ссылки left, right автоматически проинициализированы как `null`.

            return;
            // Рекурсия автоматически закончится после 'return'.
        }
    
        Insert(key, node.left);
    }
    else
    {
        // Абсолютно аналогично.
    }    
}
```

Для соблюдения данного контракта в контексте задачи *(не передавать в метод `null`)* необходимо конструировать корень дерева самостоятельно.

Понятно, что необходимости данного контракта можно избавиться, однако в таком случае **проектировать класс необходимо немного иным образом.**

Comment: то есть надо создать новый объект типа Mytree? то есть так?
if (tree == null)
        {
            tree = new MyTree();
            tree.number = key; // (**)
            tree.left = null;
            tree.right = null;
        }

Comment: по крайней мере этот вариант компилится. вот только неправильно все равно он добавляет в дерево почему-то...

Comment: @bashnia Конкретно проблему с `null` это решает. Другая ошибка в вашем коде заключается в том, что вы передаете (и изменяете) в метод `Insert` **локальную ссылку.**

--------

Т.е, если у вас есть `MyTree tree`, вы вызываете метод `Insert(..., tree.left)` и в нем как-то меняете этот самый второй параметр внутри метода, то в существующем объекте `tree` поле `tree.left` **не будет изменено.**

Comment: @bashnia Теперь подумайте, почему так происходит и, самое главное, как изменить код, чтобы он работал нужным образом.

Comment: Есть предположение, что это обходится с помощью return и сменой типа функции Insert с void на MyTree. Это так?

Comment: нет, не работает

Comment: @bashnia Ответил вам апдейтом.

Answer (score -1):

```
    MyTree tree;
    public void Insert(int key, MyTree tree)
    {          
        this.tree = tree;
        if (tree == null)
        {
            tree.number = key; // (**)
            tree.left = null;
            tree.right = null;
```

Comment: В вашем коде проблема обращения по `null` сохраняется.

Comment: не работает этот вариант